# Filter by Time(7) data type

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

How do return data where the current time is between 2 a start time and end time represented in the database as Time(7):

```
public partial class ParkingLocation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string StartAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string EndAddress { get; set; }

    public double StartLongitude { get; set; }

    public double StartLatitude { get; set; }

    public double EndLongitude { get; set; }

    public double EndLatitude { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

and the query is:

```
 public IQueryable<ParkingLocation> GetParkingLocations()
    {
        return db.ParkingLocations
            .Where(p => p.StartTime <= DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay && p.EndTime >= DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
    }
```

however, this returns an error. Can someone please tell me what I am doing worn here.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the specific error?

Comment: it just says "{"$id":"1","Message":"An error has occurred."}". Without the where clause it works fine.  Sample data is {"$id":"1","Id":1,"StartAddress":"264 dolphin street","EndAddress":"366 Dolphin Street","StartLongitude":-76.622068,"StartLatitude":39.304295,"EndLongitude":-76.625429,"EndLatitude":39.302963,"StartTime":"00:00:00","EndTime":"23:59:59"}

Comment: Something is catching the _actual_ error and replacing it with a useless generic statement.  Have you run it in the debugger to see the underlying exception?